# Reading and printing array in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator, qtspim

I'm supposed to write a program in MIPS(i use MARS) to read and print an array of integers. The only catch is that the console should look something like this:

> display array:
>   n=5
>       v[0]=1
>   v[1]=10
>   v[2]=3
>   v[3]=11
>   v[4]=100
>       Array is:1,10,3,11,100.

The console is supposed to write the parts on the left side of "=", while the user writes the values( the ones on the right side).
My issues is i dont seem to be able to store the values of the array, or at least display them, and i just get some squares.
Mine looks like this:

> display array:
>     n=5
>   v[0]=1
>   v[1]=10
>   v[2]=3
>   v[3]=11
>   v[4]=100
>      array:-some squares

(I've also added a test in the loop where i read the array to see if the integers are well read, thats why i try to print them out there as well)

```
.data 

array:        .space 40
display_array:   .asciiz"display array:"
n1:           .asciiz"\n n="
prompt1:          .asciiz"\nv["
prompt2:          .asciiz"]="
display:          .asciiz "\n array:"
iterator:     .word 0

.text
main:
#initial
li $t0,0
la $t2,array
lw $t1,iterator
li $v0,4
la $a0,display_array
syscall
#display "n="
li $v0,4
la $a0,n1
syscall
#read n
li $v0,5
syscall
#move n in t1
move $t1,$v0
for:
    bge $t0,$t1,end_for #checking if I is smaller than n
    sll $t3,$t0,2   #t3=4*I
    addu $t3,$t3,$t2 #Adding to t3 t3 and the address of the array
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,prompt1
    syscall      #Prints v[
    li $v0,1
    move $a0,$t0
    syscall     #Prints i
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,prompt2
    syscall     #Prints ]=
    li $v0,5
    syscall     #reads value
    sw $v0,0($t3)   #here's the problem, should store the value in t3
    li $v0,4
    la  $a0,0($t3)
    syscall
    addi $t0,$t0,1  #i++;
j for
end_for:
#Display Array
li $v0,4
la $a0,display 
syscall
#reinitialize i with 0
move $t0,$zero
for1:
    bge $t0,$t1,end_for1
    sll $t3,$t0,2
    addu $t3,$t3,$t2
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,0($t3)  
    syscall     #display v[i]
    addi $t0,$t0,1
j for1
end_for1:
```

Comment: You got the syscall number wrong in the printing loop.

Comment: @Jester Do you mean this? `li $v0,4
    la $a0,0($t3)  
    syscall` If so, what should i put in?

Comment: Yes. `4` is `print_string.` You want `1` for `print_int`. Also you should `lw` not `la` obviously.

Comment: @Jester Thought i tried that and it crashed but apparently it works!! Thank you very much.